# Custom web.config in Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config, setup-project

In the Setup Project I have 2 web.config files: `web.config` - used during the development and `web_dist.config` - the one that should be included into Setup Project.

I must be sure the the Setup project will NOT include the `web.config` and will always include `web_dist.config`.

In the File System -> Web Application Folder I have added the Content Files from the project.
Also included the web_dist.config and mapped it to the web.config.

But this gives the warning:

```
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\web.config')
```

And the actual config file included is `web.config` and not `web_dist.config`.

What would be the best option to include the `web_dist.config` (and named as web.config in the setup)?

Thanks,
Dmitriy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able workaround this by setting "**Build Action**" for the web.config to "**None**".
This way it doesn't get included into the setup package.

Then I just added another config file manually.

Works like a charm for this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhx4ah11(VS.80).aspx

Does following trick work in your case?

You can correct this by adding a Custom folder and setting its DefaultLocation property to the same value as the first folder, then moving the second copy of the file to the new folder.

Comment: This won't actually help as the `web.config` comes from the "Content Files" of the application and `web_dist.config` is manually added. With the workaround proposed it seems I will have the initial `web.config` in the installation which must not be done.  
Though, I got couple of ideas now. Will try to experiment.